# Save Combined Mesh into Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a scene with gameobjects that have combined meshes. Whenever I try to make that gameobject into a prefab, the prefab loses the combined mesh. Is there a way to make a gameobject with a combined mesh into a prefab?

Comment: Can you show us what your scene hierarchy looks like, particularly for the object you're trying to turn into a prefab? A before/after would be quite helpful here, to more clearly demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to put it in a empty gameobject. then prefab that empty game object

Comment: I was already try, but did not work. Is there any other way to save combined mesh in prefab?